# Is it possible to load recaptcha script only in url with fragment identifier (#)?

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

I have tried various snippets, like this:

```
<?php   
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'load_captcha_script', 100 );
   function load_captcha_script() {
    if ( !is_page( '#register' ) ) {
        wp_deregister_script('google-recaptcha');
    }
   }
```

but it doesn't work in #register section with hash, I also tried with `if (window.location.hash == "#register")`

But nothing, recaptcha doesn't load when floating form appears, Is there a snippet that only loads the script when the section appears?

Comment: The # part stays on the browser and isn't submitted to the server, so you can't detect it in PHP, no. You'd have to change the way you're enqueueing the google-recaptcha script and write JavaScript that only loads it conditionally on the hash part, e.g. using jQuery.getScript(). But then if this is a single page app which will add #register without reloading the page from the server then you'll have to handle that case too. Presumably you already have client side script that handles #register?

Comment: @Rup The problem as you say is that it does not reload the page, and about client side script I don't have much idea, so I will have to try other antispam methods, thank you very much for your answer, it has clarified my doubts.